# Problems with Wget64

Tags: command-line, wget

Attempting to write a Wget to get and save Vanguard pricing data.  So far I have 2 statements that both work correctly from the Command Line when I paste the string.  When I save the string as a bat file one works and the other gives an unexpected result.
The string that works correctly in both places is:
Wget64 --output-document=C:\Users\Default\downloads\VVA_Daily_Portfolio-%DATE:~-4%-%DATE:~4,2%-%DATE:~7,2%.html "https://personal.vanguard.com/us/funds/annuities/variable"

The string that only works in the Command Line and not as a bat file is:
Wget64 --output-document=C:\Users\Default\downloads\VVA_Fund64_History-%DATE:~-4%-%DATE:~4,2%-%DATE:~7,2%.html "https://personal.vanguard.com/us/funds/tools/pricehistorysearch?radio=1&results=get&FundType=VVAP&FundIntExt=INT&FundId=0064&fundName=0064&fundValue=0064&radiobutton2=1&beginDate=03%2F01%2F2017&endDate=12%2F31%2F2017&year=#res"
Can someone help me write the script so that the expected result is achieved.  I suspect that the Vanguard website can tell the difference between a Command Line vs bat file query, or that there is something inherently different between the two methods of execution.

ANy assistance is appreciated.  Dan

Answer (score 0):

The `cmd` command parser behaves differently in command line and batch files. In this case, the main problem is the variable expansion. In command line when a variable does not contain a value (it is undefined), the variable read operation is not removed, but inside batch files the read operation is removed.

That means that something like `echo(%thisDoesNotExist%` will output (under the assumption the variable does not exist) `%thisDoesNotExist%` in command line and nothing in batch file.

What relation has this with your problem?

If we split your `wget` in parts you have

```
Wget64 
--output-document="C:\Us ... y-%DATE:~-4%-%DATE:~4,2%-%DATE:~7,2%.html"
                               ^........^ ^.........^ ^.........^

"https://pe ... h?radio=1& ... &beginDate=03%2F01%2F2017&endDate=12%2F31%2F2017&year=#res"
                                            ^....^                 ^....^
```

You can see where the parser tries to resolve variables, correctly in the `output` case and incorrectly (from the purpouse of the command point of view) in the URL.

You need to escape (by doubling them) the percent signs that are not part of a variable read operation, ex. `... beginDate=03%%2F01%%2F2017&...`